# calculate end time from start time and duration (minutes) using pandas. Error on standard approach

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe:

Start_time | Duration(minutes)

2018-03-01 16:37:09 | 155

2018-03-01 07:02:10 | 5

2018-03-01 13:07:09 | 250

2018-03-01 20:46:34 | 180

2018-03-01 07:45:49 | 5

I want output as

Start_time | End time 
2018-03-01 16:37:09 | 2018-03-01 19:12:09

2018-03-01 07:02:10 | 2018-03-01 07:07:10

2018-03-01 13:07:09 | 2018-03-01 17:17:09

2018-03-01 20:46:34 | 2018-03-01 23:46:34

2018-03-01 07:45:49 | 2018-03-01 07:50:49

> I am using following code and getting the output for 5-10 rows as required with an warning and when I applied same code on full data set it is showing error as **TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'
>   **
>
> time_temp['End_time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(time_temp['Start_time']) + pd.to_timedelta(time_temp['Duration'], unit='m')

Error: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'
Warning: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: 

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change `DatetimeIndex` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for remove first error:

> Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int' **

```
time_temp['End_time'] = (pd.to_datetime(time_temp['Start_time']) + 
                         pd.to_timedelta(time_temp['Duration'], unit='m'))
print (time_temp)
            Start_time  Duration            End_time
0  2018-03-01 16:37:09       155 2018-03-01 19:12:09
1  2018-03-01 07:02:10         5 2018-03-01 07:07:10
2  2018-03-01 13:07:09       250 2018-03-01 17:17:09
3  2018-03-01 20:46:34       180 2018-03-01 23:46:34
4  2018-03-01 07:45:49         5 2018-03-01 07:50:49
```

For avoid second `SettingWithCopyWarning` obviously need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) if some filtering, because if you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`time_temp`), and that Pandas does warning:

```
time_temp = df[some filtering].copy()
```

There should be another problems, check [how to deal with settingwithcopywarning in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks.. It is working now. And yaa still I am getting the warning..Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @JahnabKumarDeka - `copy` does not help? There is no filtering before `time_temp['End_time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(time_temp['Start_time']) + pd.to_timedelta(time_temp['Duration'], unit='m')` ?